# Python script strange issues

Tags: python, urllib2, httplib

Hey i'm using a python script to test functionalities on web-commerce site. I put this script on pythonanywhere site, sometimes works like 7 days in a row without problems, but there are days, like this one, when i get this error:

```
Logged in with test_cart
    Open http://[***]/electronics/page/1
Search ... iphone
[****************]
    File "/home/.../cart-pickup.py", line 58, in alo
    site = opener.open(url)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1180, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1030, in getresponse
    response.begin()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 407, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 371, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
    httplib.BadStatusLine: ''
    >>>
```

Any ideas what might is?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that's a problem with your Python script, but rather a problem with the web server it's trying to talk to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can teach your program how to recover from this situation without crashing by using `try..except`:

```
try:
    site = opener.open(url)  # line 58 in cart-pickup.py
except IOError: 
    print "Error: Site not loading or it isnt UP. Retrying..." 
    # return site # This will cause a NameError if site is not defined.
    return url    # Perhaps you meant this?
except httplib.BadStatusLine:
    # log opening `url` did not succeed, or
    # queue it to be tried again, etc.
    pass
```

Comment: I'm kinda new in python. So I dont know if there is possible to have 2 excepts in a while. My code looks like this: def alo(url):
    testurl = 1
    while testurl == 1:
        try:
            site = opener.open(url)
            lagsafe = 0
        except IOError:
            print "Error: Site not loading or it isnt UP. Retrying..."

    return site
So how i can your code?

Comment: Just add the second except after your current except.

Comment: doesn't work. It say bad syntax and put it IDLE blinker (i use windows) at the second except:)

Comment: I checked my code; I don't see any error. Please post your code.

Comment: maybe im doing something wrong here : # log opening `url` did not succeed, or    # queue it to be tried again, etc. Can you give me some examples? Thanks